# workflow status column empty in library

Tags: 2010, workflow

Guys i have a weird one here.  Basically it has been reported to me that the workflow status column of one of our libraries is empty even though the workgflow has been completed.  The user reports that the column did display the status at one point but now they have dissapeared.

Ive read about sharepoint purging workflows after 69 days but surely that wouldnt remove the status value from the column.

Any ideas?

Comment: That purging thing only refers to the workflow status page, which shows up when you click "workflow history" from the ribbon or ECB. All data will still be on the list and the history list.  And it's either 60 or 90 days(can't remember which) but it's definitely not 69 days.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue once. When I just went in depth of it I found that my workflow got removed and added back under the same name. Here is the deal.

When you check the item, it had a workflow earlier. So it shows that workflow was here and it was completed in a nice way.

But your workflow is added after deleting the previous one. So the column that is created earlier vanished for a moment and added a new column under the same name. The column GUID will not be the same.

So better keep a different column which gets updated according to the status of the workflow. This will solve the problem except for the navigation link to the workflow status page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean it's showing as empty in the view.  Has the workflow been modified since this column worked last? If so it is probably storing that status in a different column now.  Go into the settings page for the view and look for an additional workflow status column.  If you find one add it to the view and remove the one that's not showing data.

Comment: There is nothing in the workflow history for the item they say has lost the approval status.  Also there isnt another column that i can see that would be for the workflow